# add element in object with concatenate name

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have object `$scope.form`. I want to add various elements in it as `$scope.form.elem1, $scope.form.elem2, $scope.form.elem3` and so on.

I tried some ways but nothing worked for me.

```
for(i = 0; i <= addr.length; i++) {
  $scope.form.elem = addr.i; //What should be here ??
}
```

Comment: are you sure you don't want `addr[i]` instead of `addr.i`?

Comment: my question is about $scope.form.elem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$scope.form["text"+variable] = addr[i];
```

Use brackets `[]` when you want to access a property with either a variable value, concatenated string or string with abnormal characters like "." .

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have the values in array `addr`. 
You can iterate the object properties with a string like this.

```
for (let i = 0; i < addr.length; i++) {
   $scope.form['yourName' + i] = addr[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking like this :

```
var noOfelements = 100; // you can have your addr array also 
var key;
for(i = 1; i <= noOfelements; i++) {
 key = "elem"+i;
 $scope.form[key] = i; //i is just for reference you can give value to each element as per your need
}
```

below is the output you will get the same output with $scope also.

[image]